# How to save a dictionary value in a viewstate?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, data-persistence

I have a questions and answers page when some questions gets hidden and some gets visible depending upon the predecessor answers. at the end i need all the answers. 
I am trying to use dictionary for this. I add answers with a key on a changed event of each control. but none of the answers are saved when i move to next section as i am hiding the previous sections.

I am trying to save it in a viewstate and add the values so that my values persists in the dictionary..
Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
    Dictionary<String, String> Answers;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Answers = (Dictionary<String, String>)ViewState["Answers"];
        ViewState["Answers"] = Answers;

    }

    protected void rdb_study_popul_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ViewState["StudySamplepopulation"] = rdb_study_popul.SelectedValue.ToString();
        Answers.Add("StudyPopulation", ViewState["StudySamplepopulation"].ToString());


    }
```

Right now, `Answers` will be empty if I move to next section.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

i am getting null reference error  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Public partial class 
    { 
 Dictionary Answers;

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Answers = ( Dictionary<String, String>)ViewState["Answers"];

    }
  protected void rdb_studysubj_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           ViewState["StudySubjectAnimal"] = rdb_studysubj.SelectedValue.ToString();
            studysub_popul.Visible = true;                
            Answers.Add("StudySubjectAnimal", ViewState["StudySubjectAnimal"].ToString());
            ViewState["Answers"] = Answers;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to update the `ViewState` in page load, because it has not changed yet, so remove the assignment of `ViewState` in your `Page_Load` and do this instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Only read the value from ViewState, do not update it here
    Answers = (Dictionary<String, String>)ViewState["Answers"];
}
```

Now in you event handler, when you are done adding to the `Answers`, then you should update your `ViewState` value, like this:

```
protected void rdb_study_popul_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ViewState["StudySamplepopulation"] = rdb_study_popul.SelectedValue.ToString();
    Answers.Add("StudyPopulation", ViewState["StudySamplepopulation"].ToString());

    // Now that you are done altering the Answers, save the updated value to ViewState
    ViewState["Answers"] = Answers;
}
```

UPDATE:

You need to check if `ViewState` is null or not, like this:

```
Dictionary<String, String> Answers = new Dictionary<String, String>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Is there anything in ViewState?
    if (ViewState["Answers"] != null)
    {
        // Yes, but only read the value from ViewState, do not update it here
        Answers = (Dictionary<String, String>)ViewState["Answers"];
    }
}
```

Note: I changed the declaration of the `Answers` dictionary to also include instantiating it, so that it will not be null.

Comment: I am getting null reference errorObject reference not set to an instance of an object.  
public partial class 
    {  Dictionary<String, String> Answers;protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { Answers = ( Dictionary<String, String>)ViewState["Answers"];
 } protected void rdb_studysubj_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e{ViewState["StudySubjectAnimal"]=rdb_studysubj.SelectedValue.ToString();studysub_popul.Visible=true;Answers.Add("StudySubjectAnimal",ViewState["StudySubjectAnimal"].ToString());ViewState["Answers"] = Answers;}

Comment: the dictionary is saving only one answer. I hide and show the controls as i move forward saving them in the dictionary but when i retrieve the answers at last it only saves the last one it doesn't displays all the answers

Comment: this is how i reading the dictionary at last                    protected void Laboratory_Capacity_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Answers = (Dictionary<String, String>)ViewState["Answers"];
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in Answers)
            {
                test.Text += "KeyName" + "::" + item.Key + "Value" + "::" + item.Value + "<br/>";

            }

        }

Comment: Is there more than one control like `rdb_study_popul` that you are handling a selected index changed event for?

Comment: yes there are multiple controls like that and each of them gets hidden as i go to next question. some of them are checkboxlist, dropdownlist,radiobuttonlist. i am trying to get the values of all these controls and save it in a dictionary with a key, i need the all the answers at last for more analaysis

Comment: it is same code file. i am actually writing a user control which has all these controls and their changed event handlers. every time an event is fired i am saving the answers and moving forward to next question. this is s single user controls with all the controls having autopostback equals true and i am using ajax for the partial postback. I am trying to save all the answers one by one in a dictionary as a collection with a key so that it will eb helppful for me to retireve at the last